# Lines in SSRS report editor do not render the same when report is viewed in browser

Tags: browser, reporting-services, rendering, line, ssrs-tablix

I have been messing with resizing lines in my report because for some reason even though I have extended them to the length I want in the report builder and they line up like I want when running the report in report builder when I view the report in a browser they extend another two or three inches across the screen. I have opened it in multiple browsers but it is still the same, the lines I want to be the same length as my text box below them, extends way out past it. Even when comparing the endpoint numbers in the line properties to the endpoint in the textbox properties they all match up.  I am trying to understand how I can make them all line up when viewed in the browser as they do in the builder.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A couple of things you can try. Make sure ALL sizes are stated using the same unit (i.e. all in cm or all in inches etc.). I know from experience this can cause strange behaviour.  It will probably be faster to open the .rdl file in a text editor and search for the units (e.g. cm & mm if you want to deal only in inches) Also, I think lines are rendered differently than other objects, could you try swapping the line for a filled textbox?

Comment: in the first image, i included the properties column in the image of the black line and it shows inches.  I checked the properties of the other line and the grey text box, they all show inches in the endpoint field.  Not sure if that is what you refer to.   Yes adding a filled in text box and expanding it to the same length as the blue line in the report builder does render correctly in the browser.  It is lined up with the grey text box shown below the two lines

Comment: with regards to the location and size units, I found that if there was any mixture in any part of the report such as a table in inches and a textbox in cm then very odd things happened, such as a textbox being twice as wide as it should be. If I get inexplicable sizing/alignment issues that's one of the things I check.

Comment: Do you have any column groups on the report? If so, this could be pushing the width out. Are you trying to make a bar graph with these lines? If so, maybe use a stacked bar chart?

Comment: @StevenWhite I do have groupings created in my chart but no these lines are just separator lines, just for looks, the chart is below them.

Comment: @AlanSchofield i will check the rdl file then and search for units.

Comment: searching the rdl i only found one instance of the word "unit" in the 3000+ lines, down at the bottom of the xml. 

<rd:ReportUnitType>Inch</rd:ReportUnitType>

Comment: There's not enough information here for us to identify or reproduce the issue. I would suggest creating a minimal working example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I just replaced them with filled in text boxes.  the units all match up and doesn't seem to be an issue.